# Return previous row value of a running total field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a field that serves as a running total (Actual Ending Balance). I now need a field that does the same, but returns the previous row's value. Here is my query:

```
select
    convert(date,c.TRANSDATE) as Transdate,

    sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'cnv%' or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%')  
    then convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate) as 'Actual 
    Ending Balance'


from AX2cTest.[dbo].CUSTTRANS_V c

group by c.TRANSDATE
```

This is sample data with the column I need (Beginning Balance):

```
Transdate   Beginning Balance   Actual Ending Balance
4/12/2019       null                  -50129.26
4/15/2019     -50129.26               -50524.21
4/25/2019     -50524.21               -52300.21
```

I ran into errors when trying to use the LAG function to solve this problem:

```
select
    convert(date,c.TRANSDATE) as Transdate,

    lag(sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 
    'cnv%' or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER 
    like 'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%')  
    then convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate)) over (order by 
    c.transdate) as 'Beginning Balance',

    sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'cnv%'or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%') then 
    convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate) as 'Actual Ending 
    Balance'


from AX2cTest.[dbo].CUSTTRANS_V c

group by c.TRANSDATE
```

Error:

> Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate

Not sure how to solve this problem or if maybe there is an alternative? Thanks

My latest attempt:

```
select
    convert(date,c.TRANSDATE) as Transdate,

    lag(sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 'cnv%' or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%')  
    then convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate)) over (order by c.transdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)  as 'Beginning Balance',



    sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 'cnv%' or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%')  
    then convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate) as 'Actual Ending Balance'

    
from AX2cTest.[dbo].CUSTTRANS_V c

group by c.TRANSDATE
```

error: The function 'lag' may not have a window frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a window frame clause:

```
(order by c.transdate rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
```

Comment: Gordon, i added that clause and received the error: The function 'lag' may not have a window frame. i'll update the post to show

Comment: @amcneil206 . . . That is because you add it to the `sum(sum())`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It may help you

```
WITH balanceCalc AS (select
    convert(date,c.TRANSDATE) as Transdate,

    sum(sum(case when c.LEDGERACCOUNT like '113120%' and (c.VOUCHER like 'civ%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'cnv%' or c.VOUCHER like 'wo%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fti%' or c.VOUCHER like 'fcr%' or c.VOUCHER like 
   'arp%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arr%' or c.VOUCHER like 'arm%' or c.VOUCHER like 'aro%')  
    then convert(decimal(10,2),c.AMOUNTMST) else 0 end)) over (order by c.transdate) as '[Actual_Ending_Balance]'


from AX2cTest.[dbo].CUSTTRANS_V c

group by c.TRANSDATE)

SELECT 
    Transdate,
    LAG([Actual_Ending_Balance],1) OVER (
        ORDER BY Transdate
    ) as 'Beginning Balance',
    [Actual_Ending_Balance]
FROM 
    balanceCalc;
```